# Net beans opens files in utf 8 even though project is in different encoding

Tags: netbeans, encoding, utf-8, ide, netbeans-8

My project is in Windows-1251 encoding. It depends on outside library which is a common dependency for many projects and therefore is stored in diferrent directory on my machine apart from projects. I added path to the library in my project's properties -> include path. The files in this library are also all in windows-1251 encoding. Net beans opens my project files correctly, thanks for that, but when I try to navigate to some method definition in library files (by ctrl+click on it) I get this warning saying the file can't be safely opened with utf-8 encoding. If I choose to open it anyway it opens with totally messed up non-ASCI characters of course. **Is it possible to tell NetBeans to open files from include path with encoding used in currently opened project?** I couldn't find any encoding-related setting apart from project's encoding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's nothing you can do about it. I switched to Eclipse.